# How do I turn .Any into a for loop?

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

I'm having some trouble turning the following code into a for loop. The purpose of the code is to check if the string has both a letter and a number in it.

```
else if (!string.Any(Char.IsLetter) || !string.Any(Char.IsDigit))
{
    return false;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's just for practice

Comment: The code, the question title and the code description all do not match each other; which question did you intend to ask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
bool anyLetter = false;
bool anyDigit = false;

foreach(var ch in str)
{
    if(char.IsLetter(ch)) anyLetter = true;
    if(char.IsDigit(ch)) anyDigit = true;

    if(anyLetter && anyDigit) break;
}

return anyLetter || anyDigit;
```

Note that if this string should contain at least one digit **and** one letter, you need to use `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 0):

Since Selman22 seems to have already answered the question, another solution I found is I guess you could also use RegEx:

```
letterCount = Regex.Matches(yourstring,@"[a-zA-Z]").Count;
numberCount = Regex.Matches(yourstring,@"\d").Count;

return letterCount != 0 && numberCount != 0;
```

Comment: "you could also use RegEx" --- any reason for that? Not to mention that `[a-zA-Z]` isn't equal to `Char.IsLetter`

Comment: No reason really, just throwing another answer into the mix. The correct answer was provided by Selman22.

Comment: it's not *another* answer. Your code doesn't take into account Unicode characters.

Comment: You might consider suggesting a correction, rather than just saying it's wrong. I'm all for a constructive correction.

Comment: well, do you know what Unicode is? Do you know what `Char.IsLetter` method does? "You might consider suggesting a correction, rather than just saying it's wron" --- it's not the point of comments to answers. If you're in doubt how to do that properly - ask a separated question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean a loop for a set of strings?

```
var src = new List<string>{"A4C", "D3F", "G7I"};
var allHaveCharAndDigit = src.TrueForAll(s => s.Any(c => char.IsLetter(c)) && s.Any(c => char.IsDigit(c)));
```